# Tricky Song Rebuses

Tags: rebus, music

The following rebuses are all clues to well known songs. See if you can get them all!

1)

[image: gingerbread house]

+

[image: state]

2)

[image: sign]

3)

[image: trees]

4)

[image: eye]

+

[image: acrobat]

5)

[image: feet]

hint:

> The fifth song is much newer than the others

hint #2:

> For the fifth song, think slang terms for shoes

Comment: Ah yes, the popular hit "Balloon Shoes".

Comment: @IanMacDonald, Definitely a classic. Let's not forget that great ballad "Bubble Toes" either...

Comment: @IanMacDonald TBH "balloon shoes" is the closest anyone has been so far

Comment: @RichardRoe hope you don't mind the edit; imgur and pinterest are both blocked on my network so all I could see was a lot of blank space.

Comment: @whrrgarbl no problem,

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1:

> **Sweet home Alabama** - Lynyrd Skynyrd (suggested by @elias)

2:

> **Yellow Submarine** - The Beatles (suggested by @Xenocacia)

3:

> **Blowin in the wind** - Bob Dylan (suggested by @elias)

4:

> **I walk the line** - Johnny Cash (suggested by @oleslaw)

5:

> **Pumped Up Kicks** - Foster the People (suggested by [@kayzeroshort](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/46684/30633))

Comment: 4. Eyeball Kid?

Comment: Errr, I don't have any idea. Ask @Xenocacia, who edited that one into my answer. Maybe through the franchise of 'Subway' sandwiches?

Comment: It's called submarine sandwich - googled this one. You learn something every day :)

Comment: cool, thanks for the explanation, @oleslaw.  we learn something new every day.

Comment: @elias- 4th could be Eyes without the face as well :) I can't see the face of the man slacking. May be too much of stress :D

Comment: @Techidiot, actually I wouldn't call any of those 'well-known songs', and both are kind of strech for me. Let's see if someone comes up with a better idea.

Comment: The #4 could be Johny Cash - I walk the line

Comment: Or I walk alone-Greenday :) One of my fav.

Comment: probably that's it, @oleslaw. an amazingly bad pun and a much more well known song than the previously mentioned ones.

Comment: @Techidiot, again, 'alone' is not the first thing that comes to my mind when I see a man on a rope. I added it to the alternative solutions though.

Comment: Eye in the sky is a famous one as well.

Comment: Sorry, wasn't checking. Yeah, such long sandwiches are sometimes known as 'heroes' or 'submarines' in the U.S. I think. I'm not actually from there so cannot confirm how common this is.

Comment: The first three are correct. I walk the line is the correct answer for four. Five is not correct. The last one is a bit of a stretch. I might start adding hints tomorrow.

Comment: #5 - These Boots are Made for Walking? or Goody Two Shoes.  I tend to think it is the Nancy Sinatra song, since it is more in the time frame of the other four songs....

Comment: Sounds good for me @APrough, I've edited it into the answer. Let's see if OP agrees.

Comment: @APrough Nope. I will say that the fifth song is much newer than the other four.

Comment: Then Goody Two Shoes.  Or if newer than that, Walking on Air.

Comment: @APrough, good answer and not to be confused with Believe it or Not :)

Comment: Sorry @APrough still not right

Comment: Pumped Up Kicks

Comment: Got it! Good work!

Answer (score 2):

What about...

> 1. Sweet home Alabama
>  2. Yellow submarine
>  3. Blowin' in the wind
>  4. I walk the line
>  5. Walk on water

What I think the last picture (5) is:

> Jesus shoes, shoes invented to walk on water.

Comment: Sorry, #5 is not it

Answer (score 1):

5

> "Pumped Up Kicks" - Foster the People

Comment: Yeah that's the one.

Answer (score 0):

For song 5

> Walking on Air by Katy Perry

Comment: again, no, but you;re getting a bit warmer

Answer (score 0):

I got 5, I think

> Walking on air

Comment: no, but you're moving in kind of the right direction